# In this sentence, "just" and "exactly" pretty much mean the same thing, right?

Tags: meaning

I know the word "just" has lots of meanings. I just want to make sure my understanding about this meaning of it is correct.

> We need someone who has experience in marketing and teaching, and I think Alex is **just** the woman for the job.

[source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experience)

In that sentence, "just" and "exactly" pretty much mean the same thing, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have it. This particular sense of 'just' is very close to 'exactly' in the sentence given. Quite right for you to say that 'just' has many meanings, though in this case I'd even go further as to say many shades of meaning.

I'd say that 'exactly' might be a tad more reflective of a sort of excess in precision, and maybe a tad more emphatic, but they are extremely close even so.