# meaning of "Star Trek Vulcan precision"

Tags: meaning

I know Vulcans are a fictional extraterrestrial humanoid species in the Star Trek universe and media franchise.

I also know precision means "the quality, condition, or fact of being exact and accurate."

A post [In this sentence, "just" and "exactly" pretty much mean the same thing, right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/246413/112757) says

> I'd say that 'exactly' might be a tad more reflective of a sort of **Star Trek Vulcan precision**, and maybe a tad more emphatic, but they are extremely close even so.

what's the meaning of "Star Trek Vulcan precision"?

Comment: Why not ask that in a comment on the answer that contained it?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty this site tells me "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty OP does not have sufficient reputation to comment on posts yet. I would point out that the reference is inapt—the [Star Trek Vulcan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan) is not known for precision, but for logic.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: That's funny. 'inapt'! They are known for logic certainly, but watch any of the original episodes where Spock was showing off. It very often included excessively exact, extreme detail. Of course you are free to your thought on this, but I stand by the observation.

Comment: It might be as well to allow comments on answers to one's own question regardless of points, to facilitate dialogue.

Comment: @Yishmeray "Star Trek Vulcan precision" in [that post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/246413/112757) means a degree of super duper precise, probably more precise than the most precise thing on the earth, right?

Comment: @Yishmeray Indeed, but I would suggest you edit your post in the other thread to explain what you mean; particularly on a site for English Language Learners, colorful cultural references do not improve comprehension for someone who doesn't get the reference. This isn't explicitly noted in the [Contributors' Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783) but is part and parcel of avoiding idiomatic expressions, sports metaphors, or movie quotes.

Comment: That sounds very helpful. Thank you @choster. This is new to me, if English is not. I appreciate the kindness.

Comment: and yes, you are right, @Piete3r. That was what I meant.

Comment: To avoid future confusion for our learners, I have removed the 'colorful' reference, with thanks to choster for the suggestion. My apologies @Piete3r for any confusion caused. I believe you have gotten the meaning anyway, as you so clearly demonstrated in your comment above.

Comment: @Yishmeray Thanks for your confirmation. Does "colorful" mean something involves "species"?

Comment: No, sorry. 'colorful' was the term used by @choster to try, kindly, to emphasize the nature of the comparison I made, which was maybe not the best choice. A colorful phrase or term is more poetic or emotional or lively or exciting. It does not rely solely on bare facts such as weight, dimension, color, or things you can count. Think of the difference between the way the law is written (very dry, formal, even harsh) and the way a singer describes things. It often includes comparisons with other things, or appeals to beauty. I see that I am not defining this well. Apologies!